# How to import Excel file data into database?

Tags: database, excel, datagridview, import

I've created a form where the manager can import an Excel file to DataGridView but I'm having trouble saving it to the database.

Reason: So when the manager imports the rota Excel file to DataGridView I want the other users to see it in a different form.
My form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class EmployeeRota : Form
    {
        string con = "Data Source=dqq5ndqef2.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=False;User ID=richardjacobs97;Password=;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        DataTable dt;
        public EmployeeRota()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PathCpnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathCpnn);

            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            myDataAdapter.Update(dt);
        }

        private void EmployeeRota_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = con;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Rota (Id, Name, Date) Values (@Id, @Name, @Date)");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                int i = 0;
                i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                sda.Update(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database:  [Database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9eVi.png)

[image: Database pic]

Form:  [Form pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE1pu.png)

[image: Form pic]

Any suggestions why I get this error?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at i=dataGridView1.Rowcount-1; and see if dataGridView1.RowCount is 0. That would cause the AddWithValue code to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving that error because the Load function runs when the page is first opened. You should move this into a separate functions so that it can be called at select times, maybe from a button click. This is prior to any data source being applied to the 
DataGridView. You need to add the following to make sure there are rows in the table.

```
i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
if(i<0) // Meaning that the row count was 0
{
return;
}
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
```

Comment: I have moved the code to a button click and i have done as you have said but i now get an error.                                                                                                                An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Login.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is the debugger breaking for you at the point where you receive the Exception? Knowing where it encounters that NullReferenceException will help.

Comment: There are no errors now but nothing stores in the database? any suggestions?